# SSIS cannot change Project ProtectionLevel to Encrypt sensitive data with password

Tags: ssis, project

I am using VS2019 to create SSIS projects. I have tried to update one of my current projects and I have created a new project to try and update the protection level. When trying to update the protection level from EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey to Encrypt sensitive data with password. When trying to do this it allows me to enter a password, but the OK button is disabled. I have tried all kinds of password combos to make sure they are long enough and complex enough. Any ideas how to get by this?
[image]

Comment: There should be a "Retype Password" under that Password box.   For some reason it's being cropped on your system.   Until you retype it to match the OK will stay grayed.

Comment: Thanks to vhoang, I had tried to expand the dialog box like I have others in VS for SSIS, but that did not work. What I did do is type in the password in the password box. Then I tabbed to the next box, which is not visible and entered the password again, in the confirm password box. And the OK button became available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vhoang for pushing me just a little further. I had tried to expand the dialog box like I have others in VS for SSIS, but that did not work. What I did do is type in the password in the password box. Then I tabbed to the next box, which is not visible and entered the password again (with faith that I was in the confirm password box). And yep the OK button became available.